# Execute function on Scroll jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm misunderstanding the scroll() function. I'm wishing to if a panel is open execute a function if the main window is scrolled up or down. This is my code that does nothing.

```
if('#specsallA:visible').scroll(function(){
              $('#specsbar').animate({
          width:'190px'
          }, '500'); $('.products').animate({
          width:'168px'
          }, '500'); $('#specsallA').hide();  $('#specsall').show();
          });
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slight misunderstanding.  Easiest way is to put your if() test inside the event callback

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#specsallA').is(':visible')) {
        // do your special stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Be careful of really slowing down your site: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   doSomething();
})
```